# Ionic build android showig error no ANDROID_HOME

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I have set ANDROID_HOME in ~/.profile.
echo $ANDROID_HOME also points to the sdk. But on executing ionic platform add android it returns an error no ANDROID_HOME or android in path.

Someone please.

Comment: My Answer will fix your problem [Fix Android Home Error ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35110403/failed-to-find-android-home-environment-variable-try-setting-setting-it-manua/40061081#40061081)

Answer (score -1):

try sudo ANDROID_HOME=[YOUR ANDROID HOME] ionic build android

sometimes your ~/.profile does not get executed when building as someone else