# Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable. Try setting setting it manually

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, environment-variables

I am trying to build an ionic project. I have set up environment for ionic and android in ubuntu. But don't know why the following error is showing on terminal ...

```
Error: Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable. Try setting setting it manually.
Failed to find 'android' command in your 'PATH'. Try update your 'PATH' to include path to valid SDK directory.
```

I have set up android home as followings ...

```
userPC:/codes/myApp$ export ANDROID_HOME=/opt/android-sdk-linux
userPC:/codes/myApp$ export ANDROID_PLATFORM_TOOLS=/opt/android-sdk-linux/platform_tools
userPC:/codes/myApp$ export ANDROID_TOOLS=/opt/android-sdk-linux/tools
userPC:/codes/myApp$ PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME:$ANDROID_TOOLS:$ANDROID_PLATFORM_TOOLS
```

my android-sdk-linux is in /opt/ itself. From terminal I can run **android** command. So, I think environment variable is not the main issue. While I am trying to build ionic project, it shows `Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable.` I am using Android SDK Build Tools 22 and ionic latest version.

Can anyone tell me how can I solve this issue? I have searches a lot but everywhere I found to setup android sdk and environment variable path correctly. But I already have set up all these things. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think you are doing everything right except for the `bin` part.Add ANDROID_HOME environment variable to path and point out the corresponding bin directory as:

```
1.export ANDROID_HOME=/path/to/android/SDK
2.export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/bin
```

when you issue `studio.sh` command on the command line, it looks for the `bin directory` in the path which contain executables! `studio.sh` is the one in this case.

For more information,[Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34578181/error-failed-to-find-android-home-environment-variable-try-setting-setting/34578934#34578934)

Hope this was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

**After long time on search. To make a final fix for this problem**
Follow Theses incrustation and it will fix it Correctly

1. Delete your current installation of node & npm & ionic & cordova
2. Install nvm follow this [install nvm ubuntu](http://www.liquidweb.com/kb/how-to-install-nvm-node-version-manager-for-node-js-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts/)
3. Install node with nvm  follow this [install node via nvm](https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/how-to-install-node-js-via-nvm-node-version-manager-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts/)
4. Install ionic and cordova

   `npm install -g cordova ionic`
5. Never use root to install node ,npm ,ionic or cordova
6. Set your Android Home

   `export ANDROID_HOME=/path/to/android/SDK`

   `export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/bin`

After that its worked fine for my and ionic can see Android SDK home