# Windows : Error: Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable. Failed to find 'android' command in your 'PATH'

Tags: android, node.js, windows, eclipse, cordova

i create project in phonegap with node js, but next after create project i want to add platform android but eror as follow is

**Error: Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable. Try setting setting it manually. Failed to find 'android' command in your 'PATH'. Try update your 'PATH' to include path to valid SDK directory.**

can you help me because I've tried some tutorials here but still can no working ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to find 'ANDROID\_HOME' environment variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36198165/failed-to-find-android-home-environment-variable)

Comment: Your answer is here. http://stackoverflow.com/a/36201240/3145960

Comment: have you set your android sdk ??