# unable to generate apk in ionic framework issue with android sdk

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am new to ionic and android development.I have created a sample HelloWorld application which works fine in the browser when I try to generate the unsigned APK I am facing the following issues [Build Issue Ionic Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzB4n.png).I have installed latest android SDK via android studio.These are the screenshots of installed SDKs [Installed SDKs Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UeJTM.png).I have also tried to modify the environment variable Android_Home path to 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\build-tools'.Still facing the same issue.

FYI: I am using Windows as my development environment.

Comment: Are you using window,linux or mac please check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36198165/failed-to-find-android-home-environment-variable

Comment: Thank you Manoj I am using Windows as my development environment.

Comment: kaniarasan please set you environment variable Android_Home path and there is no other issue just setup your environment variable and let me know it's work or not

Comment: still i am facing the same issue manoj.I have added Android_Home variable to my sysment variable and updated the path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ionic thinks your Android SDK is at the file path 'C:/Android' because it found adb there. It's definitely not there because 'platform-tools' isn't there. Try deleting that file (or folder if you don't need it) and changing your ANDROID_HOME path variable to the location that Android Studio says your SDK is at. If you navigate to that folder yourself you should see a 'platform-tools' folder there.

Comment: thank you Medivh it working after deleting the Android folder in c