# Ionic path not found on linux

Tags: android, ubuntu, ionic-framework, path, sdk

I have this problem on ionic 3:

When i run this:

```
ionic cordova run android --device
```

i see this:

```
> cordova run android
Error: Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable. Try setting setting it manually.
Failed to find 'android' command in your 'PATH'. Try update your 'PATH' to include path to valid SDK directory.

[ERROR] Cordova encountered an error.
        You may get more insight by running the Cordova command above directly.

[ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova run android (exit code 1).
```

I do not know what the solution is.
I would like to know the link to download sdk for android and the way I have to set the path variable, I tried but I can not

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to find 'ANDROID\_HOME' environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36198165/failed-to-find-android-home-environment-variable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to confirm that your development environment has been set correctly.

Quoting from [spring.io](http://spring.io/guides/gs/android/):

> ### Set up the Android development environment
>
> Before you can build Android applications, you must install the
>   Android SDK. Installing the Android SDK also installs the AVD Manager,
>   a graphical user interface for creating and managing Android Virtual
>   Devices (AVDs).
>
> 1. From the [Android web site](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html), download the
>      correct version of the Android SDK for your operating system.
> 2. Unzip the archive to a location of your choosing. For example, on Linux or Mac, you can place it in the root of your user directory. See
>      the [Android
>      Developers](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html)
>      web site for additional installation details.
> 3. Configure the `ANDROID_HOME` environment variable based on the location of the Android SDK. Additionally, consider adding
>      `ANDROID_HOME/tools`, and `ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools` to your PATH.
>
> #### Mac OS X
>
> ```
> export ANDROID_HOME=/<installation location>/android-sdk-macosx
> export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
> ```
>
> #### Linux
>
> ```
> export ANDROID_HOME=/<installation location>/android-sdk-linux
> export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
> ```
>
> #### Windows
>
> ```
> set ANDROID_HOME=C:\<installation location>\android-sdk-windows
> set PATH=%PATH%;%ANDROID_HOME%\tools;%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools
> ```
>
> The Android SDK download does not include specific Android platforms.
>   To run the code in this guide, you need to download and install the
>   latest SDK platform. You do this by using the Android SDK and AVD
>   Manager that you installed in the previous section.
>
> 1. Open the **Android SDK Manager** window:
>
>    ```
>    android
>    ```
>
>    **Note:** If this command does not open the **Android SDK Manager**,
>      then your path is not configured correctly.
> 2. Select the **Tools** checkbox.
> 3. Select the checkbox for the **latest Android SDK**.
> 4. From the **Extras** folder, select the checkbox for the **Android Support Library**.
> 5. Click the **Install packages...** button to complete the download and installation.
>
>    **Note:** You may want to install all the available updates, but be
>      aware it will take longer, as each API level is a large download.