# Cordova unable to find Android SDK folder

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

Running

```
cordova run android
```

Gives an error:

> Android SDK not found. Make sure that it is installed. If it is not at the default location, set the ANDROID_HOME environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @dineshaws at this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/41137754/51789

The answer was an out of date platform.

```
Installed platforms:
  android 5.1.1
  browser 4.1.0
```

At the time of this writing, cordova platform Android 7.1.1 is current.

The following steps resolved my issue (Latest Android Studio):

```
cordova platform rm android
cordova platform add android
```